# How to find highest alphabet in a String?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Consider the example "**DBCZAQW**"
I have to find the charcter which is greatest among other characters in the string(Z in this case)
I have sorted the arrays in ths manner

```
 String s="DBCZAQW";
 char arr[]=s.toCharArray();
 Arrays.sort(arr);
 System.out.println(arr[s.length()-1]);
```

Is there any procedure to find the character other than **sorting**????

Comment: please format your posts properly next time.

Comment: You could convert it to a `char` array and iterate over it, but i think sorting is faster...

Comment: ok Nomesh. Thank you for formating it :)

Comment: Iteration will be faster than sorting, you can iterate only once and use a variable to keep track of highest till now hence an order of n, while for sorting order will be nlogn

Comment: Side question: is case important? If not then you'd probably want to call `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` first - unless you can ensure the case is always the same.

Comment: Are you really only looking for the highest letter in the alphabet? That is a very simple task, are you sure you interpreted the question correctly? (assuming homework)

Comment: Actually I did not consider the cases.(either upper or lower). But if i sort using Arrays.sort(),according to largest unicode values value it is geting printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through all characters in the string

```
char result = s.charAt(0);
for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
    result = result > s.charAt(i) ? result : s.charAt(i);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Note**: be careful with empty string :)

Comment: This is better than sorting

Comment: If the goal find the 'highest alphabet' means finding the largest letter then you can break from the loop once you have found a 'Z'.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster that's correct :) , I prefer add `&& result < 'Z'` in the for loop condition (look nicer, I guess), but we need to wait if OP want highest alphabet or just highest character.

Comment: @pham Trung. I can not predit the input right. Here is an example  s="ADEQC". Here there is no 'Z'